# How to create Repeater field in Redux Framework from wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, redux-framework

Repeater field plugin is purchased in Redux framework. But I am creating it as a custom filed .

I have created 3 fields(title, phone, Textarea) with add more and delete button. In this, I want to add upload button along with that three fields . But I failed to add upload button . I tried a lot but it's not working .

Can you please tell me what is the way to add upload image button in custom field extension.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. This way, it is much easier to help you. Show all the *relevant* code but not all the code you got. Best regards

Answer (score 3):

```
$fields = array(
    'id'=>'multi-text',
    'type' => 'multi_text',
    'title' => __('Multi Text Option - Color Validated', 'textdomain'),
    'validate' => 'color',
    'subtitle' => __('If you enter an invalid color it will be removed. Try using the text "blue" as a color.  ;)', 'texdoma'),
    'desc' => __('This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'redux-framework-demo')
    ),
);
```

Example Usage

**This example in based on the example usage provided above. Be sure to change $redux_demo to the value you specified in your opt_name argument.**

```
global $redux_demo;

echo 'First Text Entry: ' . $redux_demo['multi-text'][0];
```

// The array number of additional entries will increase by one.

Comment: Just defining an array will create the repeater field ! How will that array be used ?